# Opening applications won't show if youtube is full screen

Tags: release-juno

When youtube is on full screen mode, opening applications `⌘ + space` won't take precedence over youtube video.

Comment: True, and not only for Youtube, but for all fullscreen media (VLC, Videos, fullscreen playback in the browser). So, maybe it's not a bug, but a feature? :)

Comment: Once I couldn't `alt+tab` in full screen, I realized that it was most likely a feature.

Comment: Ohh, fullscreen media opens in a new multitasking view, that's why I couldn't `alt+tab`